# How to test HTML span elements returned from JS by Jest testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component which accepts certain parameters and returns a HTML span element. I am trying to write a Jest test for a component which takes in a String value and returns a HTML span tag element with the string value.

```
<span class=... >
value
</span>
```

I want to test this component via Jest and this is the test that I have written.

```
import Value from "./value";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

describe("Test Value Component", () => {
    const value = "test";
    const component = shallow(Value);
    expect(component(value)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

However, this is not working as the test throws the error - `ShallowWrapper can only wrap valid elements`.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) - it needs an *element*, `shallow(<Value />)`.

Comment: I tried that as well, that is also giving a syntax error when I try to wrap it.

Comment: What syntax error? Is your project actually set up to transpile JSX? If this is unfamiliar I'd recommend using Create React App, which also comes with React Testing Library, rather than Enzyme.